# php compact() not work for predifined variables

Tags: php

Do `compact()` not work for predefined variables ($_GET, $_POST, $_SETVER, ...)?

```
function foo($bar) {
  doSomething(compact('bar', '_POST'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works only outside functions.

You should re-assign.

```
var_dump(compact('_POST')); // It's work.

function wrong1() { return compact('_POST'); } // Notice: Undefined variable

function wrong2() { global $_POST; return compact('_POST'); } // Notice: Undefined variable

(function() use ($_POST) { return compact('_POST'); })(); // Fatal error: Cannot use auto-global as lexical variable

function ok() { $data = $_POST; return compact('data'); } // It's work.
```